# AUI in-built validator not working

Tags: user-interface, liferay, validation, alloy-ui

I wrote some simple code in liferay to make use of the in-built aui validator, like so:

```
<div id="addDiv">

    <aui:form name="fmAdd" id="fmAdd" action="<%= addURL.toString() %>" method="post">
        <aui:fieldset>
            <div>
                <aui:input id="addName" name="name">
                    <aui:validator name="required"  />
                </aui:input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <aui:input id="addDescription" name="desc" >
                    <aui:validator name="required"  />
                </aui:input>
            </div>
            <aui:button-row>
                <aui:button type="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
            </aui:button-row>
        </aui:fieldset>
    </aui:form>
</div>
```

In another project the same code works fine, and for this jsp it recognises that it's a required field since it appends (required) at the end of the input labels. However, the javascript validation doesn't work. When I click the button without filling in anything the whole form just submits anyway.

Am I missing something? I'm very confused right now so any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

**Edit: For some reason, this problem solved itself without me doing anything. I'm not sure what happened, but it suddenly started working. Can someone advise me as to what I should do with this post? Is there a way to remove it?**

Answer (score 2):

I think I have figured it out. I faced the same problem. Validation stopped working when I added another form in an included page.
When I added 'name' attribute to each forms it started working again.

Comment: My form had a name and I didn't have multiple forms on the same page, so my issue was probably different. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It can very well be a bug that is mentioned here in the link.
 http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-15050